# allow_url_fopen is on, still can't fetch data

Tags: php

What can I do if I turn on the access but still get php errors?

```
Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in ------------- on line 40

Warning: file_get_contents(http://finance.google.co.uk/finance/info?client=ig&q=NASDAQ:MSFT) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in --------------- on line 40
```

[image]

Comment: Do you use PHP by command line or in your browser? Both have different configurations.

Comment: I'm not using command line.

Comment: Create a file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it, open it up in your browser, and check which php.ini files are parsed. You may be editing the wrong one.

Comment: I've been editing the wrong php.ini, I have to look for a php5.ini. Anyways, it's hard to find it, these absolute paths don't say too much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
if (ini_get("allow_url_fopen") == 1) {
echo "allow_url_fopen is ON";
} else {
echo "allow_url_fopen is OFF";
}
print ini_get("allow_url_fopen");
```

or you can try a different method

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $return;
}
$string = curl('http://www.example.org/myfile.php');
```

Try to add this code to your .`htaccess` file:

```
php_value allow_url_fopen On
```

if using `wamp` `php.ini` are two folders  `C:\wamp\bin\apache\apacheVersion\bin` and `C:\wamp\bin\php\phpVersion` so make setting `allow_url_fopen=on` in both files

Comment: I think quotes are needed around "on" with `ini_set()`. But on top of that, I think it needs to be a "1", per http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php

Comment: No I'm not using WAMP, not using XAMPP, this is not a local webserver, all I can edit is `php.ini` I guess.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen is OFF`

Answer (score -1):

it took me 3 days to figure it out.
Decided to post this in case you have a similar situation like me.
In my case, I am using a shared hosting setup and I was trying to install composer and then slim framework.

From CPanel I had Php 7.2 selected and phar and json enabled.
But from SSH shell when I would run composer commands it would say phar and json extensions are not installed. Moreover the php version was 5.6.

```
php --ini
```

or

```
php -v
```

then I checked all aliases on SSH to see which PHP was binded

```
alias
```

So I learnt that SSH shell PHP version has nothing to do with front-end cpanel php.
bothe are completely separate setups.

now to update my php version for shell I aliased php to php72 folder via shell command.
Then the problem was how to enable phar and json libraries. So I passed them in my command to use those libraries when executing my composer.phar scripts.

```
$ php -d extension=phar.so -d extension=json.so composer.phar require slim/slim:4.0.0
```

You can also change the default PHP for your SSH by updating the .bash_profile and define the alias in their for php as;

```
alias php='your php folder path'
```

the .bash_profile file will be in the root directory of your user folder if you FTP it. CPanel file explorer doesn't show hidden or other types of files. It only shows certain extension files.

And it finally worked and installed my slim framework.
I hope this helps those who are struggling.

Peace! 
Proud Pakistani